# Web Forms for Marketers and language

Tags: wffm, multilingual

We are using the WFFM module with a custom save action.

Now, running through the `AdaptedResultList` we can access the fields with data. In this field set there is a property called `FieldName`. In my developer environment this follows the language the form is submitted in. But in the production environment it takes the language of the last updated version of the form.

What should I do to get the form name in a language-consistent way? The overall problem is that the language of `FieldName` changes in an unpredictable way.

Comment: Just to confirm do you have multiple languages present in production? Are these present on your developer machine also?

Comment: Yes: The form exists in both danish and english.

Comment: Which version of the module and version of sitecore you on?

Comment: Everything is in version 8.1

Comment: Can you clarify, not really clear what is the problem in your question.

Comment: I had the following issue, in the form designer, for a form in 2 language: When I was in english, and save my form, the **Item Name** of each field was translated to the english version, when I was in German (the other language) and Save, all the **Item Name** where renamed to the German version. If it's your case, the support have a solution for that.

Comment: @Bazijjoba Which support case ID are you referring to?

Comment: From @Bazijjoba on Slack: Hey, I saw you comment on Stack Exchange, Unfortunately, I cannot add or edit my message ... (reputation thing on SO) but here is the Reference number : 112928

Comment: How about trying first to get the language of the site and then to retrieve the item based on the language and then to access the fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen the same behavior - what I concluded out of some tests is that WFFM is taking the "title" of the field in which the form was first requested. After that, it will stay in that language until the site restarts. WFFM caches some stuff it should not, and I assume this is one of those. We've had other issues with translations in WFFM due to the same phenomenon (in error reporting).

So, as that actually could not really be fixed in our version and we could not wait for a patch, we used the fieldID property instead like this:

```cs
var fieldItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(new ID(field.FieldID));
// use fieldItem.Name
```

We continued with the fieldItem.Name which is the actual name of the field item in Sitecore - this will not change when switching languages.